# Flaky location reporting on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

I am writing an iPhone app which reports location using standard location tracking. The CLLocationManager setup is as follows:

```
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 250.0
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

(For now, I want pretty verbose and accurate reporting, but I will probably be able to relax things later. For now, I am just trying to get my code to work at all.)

I am testing on two iPhone 6s. Both were inside, in my home all day.

Phone #1 showed few updates, and all within a very tight radius, well under the 250 meter distance filter used to configure the location manager.

Phone #2 showed over 100 updates in 5 hours, varying over perhaps one mile, with the points arranged very close to a straight line. There is a big cluster of points in my home, another big cluster at the other end of the line, a mile away, and fewer points in between.

Both phones are on the Verizon network, and connected to the same wifi router.

Any ideas what might be causing this great discrepancy in behavior?  I'm guessing that phone #2 is sometimes reporting based on wifi and sometimes based on cell tower triangulation (and sometimes combining the two?), whereas phone #1 is using just wifi. Why phones matching in hardware, iOS version, cell network and router should differ in behavior like this is puzzling.

Comment: The location manager is stored in a local variable?? And where's your delegate method where you're reading these results?

Comment: No, this is not complete code. I wrote a LocationMonitor class, in which locationManager is a field, the LocationManager is its own delegate, and implements locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]).

Comment: So you want help but you refuse to show real code?

Comment: I have no problem showing real code, but it seems like the code isn't the problem. Locations are being reported, just in drastically different ways on two phones. I'm looking for ideas on how to investigate this problem.

Comment: But here is the code: http://pastebin.com/rRT2ffxF